# Как перебрать все теги с классом и найти нужный?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив с данными из БД, который я перебераю

```
 foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    <select class="active" name="active">
       <option><?=$value['active']?></option>
       <option class="sec_act"></option>
    </select>
   }
```

Получается один `option` пустой, а у другого значение либо `active`, либо `noactive`
Как мне с помощью `js` перебрать весь `.active` и заполнить пустой `option`, там где уже есть active, добавить `noactive` и наобарот?

Примерно такая попытка была у меня:

```
$('.active').each(function(){

    if($(this).val() == 'active'){
    $(this).closest('.sec_act').html('noactive');
       }else{
    $(this).closest('.sec_act').html('active');
        }
            });
```

Comment: абсолютно непонятно что есть на входе и что надо получить на выходе. Если нужно решение на js, зачем давать код на php? Добавь конечную разметку.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp на jQuery по-моему так `$(".className")`

Comment: Вместо closest,  надо было children )) и все работает

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.active option:first-child').each(function (index, option) {
    if ($(option).val() == 'active')
        $(option).closest('select.active').find('option.sec_act').text('noactive')
    else
        $(option).closest('select.active').find('option.sec_act').text('active')
})
```